# Is it ok to wear clothes with stars or nature on them?

Tags: salat

Is it ok to wear clothing with stars or trees (anything to do with nature or space)?
Does it invalidate prayer or reading Quran from a mus'haf?
I am a woman so I cover up my clothing in black abaya when I pray.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it permissible to earn money from painting cityscapes and scenery?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48345/is-it-permissible-to-earn-money-from-painting-cityscapes-and-scenery)